# Best way of presenting persons in a brochure/three-column page

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout

In a brochure (A5) I am designing in InDesign CC I would like to present several persons. Currently my layout is designed such that I divided the page into three columns, place the image of the person in the outermost column, a small text box below the image for the name/position of the person and use the space in the other two columns for text describing the person. This text is placed in a separate text box. Works so far.
Still, I am running into several annoyances:

- If the text describing the person is too long, the large text box is higher than the image and the short text combined
- Each time I would like to add a new person, I have to create two text boxes and an image, and align them. Furthermore, when moving them around, I have to keep in mind to mark them all at once to avoid re-aligning afterwards.
- Each time adding a new person means that I have to put the person into the correct slot (assumed I would like to sort them according to their names), and shuffling all the other persons around. Pre-setting the persons is not possible, unfortunately

Thus, are there easier ways for dealing with this situation?

The layout I had in mind looks as follows:
[image]

Comment: I think the best way to get an answer is showing in images what you are explaining in your question.

Comment: I added an image of the layout I had in mind